# How to disable billing address in checkout page?

Tags: magento2.4.2, billing-address, checkout-page, disable

I want to disable the "Billing address" from checkout page in Magento 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For hidden billing address fields (form), but it still do some extra work for validation.

`etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="disable_billing_address" type="Vender\DisableBillingAddress\Plugin\DisableBillingAddress" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`Plugin/DisableBillingAddress.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vender\DisableBillingAddress\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as M2LayoutProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class DisableBillingAddress
{
    private $arrayManager;

    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function afterProcess(M2LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        // Billing Address fields
        $paths = $this->arrayManager->findPaths('form-fields', $jsLayout);
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $jsLayout = $this->arrayManager->remove($path, $jsLayout);
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```